# How to make operators execute only once in rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs

`$` will send out events continuously.

I only want to execute the `// do2` tap operator once.

My idea is to use `scan` and `filter`, but this is a bit redundant because two operators are used

```
import { Subject, tap } from 'rxjs'

const $ = new Subject<void>()

declare const flag: boolean

$.pipe(
  tap(() => {
    // do1
  }),
  tap(() => {
    // do2
  })
).subscribe()
```

Answer (score 1):

Subjects are multicast and can have multiple subscriptions, have a second subscription that uses a `take(1)` to only emit once.

```js
const { Subject, take, tap } = rxjs;

const $ = new Subject();

$.pipe(
  tap(() => {
    console.log('Do 1');
  })
).subscribe();

$.pipe(
  take(1),
  tap(() => {
    console.log('Do 2');
  })
).subscribe();

$.next();
$.next();
$.next();
$.next();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.0/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha512-v0/YVjBcbjLN6scjmmJN+h86koeB7JhY4/2YeyA5l+rTdtKLv0VbDBNJ32rxJpsaW1QGMd1Z16lsLOSGI38Rbg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```